# How to use win32 'IOpenControlPanel' interface from managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to implement the **[IOpenControlPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** interface, which is not documented in sites like **[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/)**, so for this task I built the definitions from scratch as I think they should be, then I tried to manually retrieve the interface CLSID from registry, which seems to be `D11AD862-66DE-4DF4-BF6C-1F5621996AF1`, and a Class that implements that inferface, which seems to be `06622D85-6856-4460-8DE1-A81921B41C4B`.

The problem is that in the following code If I call `GetCurrentView` function I don't get the expected value, and a call to `Open` function does nothing (I'm using a proper canonical name like `Microsoft.DefaultPrograms` as explained in **[this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** from **[this list of canonical names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**.)

```vb
Dim cp As New COpenControlPanel
Dim view As ControlPanelView
DirectCast(cp, IOpenControlPanel).GetCurrentView(view)
DirectCast(cp, IOpenControlPanel).Open("Microsoft.DefaultPrograms", "", Nothing)
```

So, I think that my definitions are wrong in some way, I need help to fix it.

---

These are the the definitions:

VB.Net:

```vb
Friend NotInheritable Class NativeMethods

    Enum ControlPanelView As Integer
        Classic = 0
        Category = 1
    End Enum

    <ComImport()>
    <Guid("06622D85-6856-4460-8DE1-A81921B41C4B")>
    Class COpenControlPanel
    End Class

    <ComImport>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    <Guid("D11AD862-66DE-4DF4-BF6C-1F5621996AF1")>
    Public Interface IOpenControlPanel

        <PreserveSig()>
        Function Open(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByVal name As String,
                      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByVal page As String,
                                                      ByVal punkSite As IntPtr
        ) As Integer ' HResult

        <PreserveSig()>
        Function GetPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> ByVal name As String,
                       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal path As StringBuilder,
                                                         ByVal bufferSize As Integer
        ) As Integer ' HResult

        <PreserveSig()>
        Function GetCurrentView(ByRef refView As ControlPanelView
        ) As Integer ' HResult

    End Interface

End Class
```

C# (online translation):

```cs
internal sealed class NativeMethods {

    public enum ControlPanelView : int {
        Classic = 0,
        Category = 1
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("06622D85-6856-4460-8DE1-A81921B41C4B")]
    class COpenControlPanel {}

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("D11AD862-66DE-4DF4-BF6C-1F5621996AF1")]
    public interface IOpenControlPanel
    {

        [PreserveSig()]
        int Open([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string name, 
                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string page, 
                 IntPtr punkSite);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int GetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string name, 
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder path, 
                    int bufferSize);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int GetCurrentView(ref ControlPanelView refView);

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot create an interface. You need to create an object that provides (implements) the interface.

Comment: @GSerg, I have taken for reference the following example with **IShellLink** interface, which is defined only the interface and successfully instantiaded using the same technique that I'm trying to apply: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IShellLinkW.html

Comment: Well, [you defined `ShellLink`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18885865/11683), a class that implements `IShellLink` and has its own `CLSID_ShellLink`, and you instantiated that class. Same here.

Comment: @GSerg sorry you have reason, and thanks for clarifying that, then maybe you know how I can find a class that implements IOpenControlPanel?.

Comment: CLSID_OpenControlPanel = "{06622D85-6856-4460-8DE1-A81921B41C4B}" supposedly.

Comment: Yes I seen the same in the registry, that reffers to **COpenControlPanel** name, now I don't get any exception but my code is not working, I mean that a call to any function does nothing, or in case of GetCurrentView I don't get the expected result, so probablly my definition is wrong, I'll update the code and reformat my question in some minutes.

Comment: `StringBuilder` should be `ByVal`, and do you have `Option Strict On`? Also try to pass what `GetCurrentView` returns to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t3ykxc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Comment: Yes I have Option Strict On, the paramater I assigned as Stringbuilder shouldn't be ByVal I think, because is marked as [Out] saying this: **When this method returns, contains the path of the specified Control Panel item as a Unicode string**, it expects a by reference object.

Comment: Yes, you pass `StringBuilder` `ByVal` in that case.

Comment: You are making the classic mistake. You can't tell whether the problem is in how you declare the type or how you use it. Remove the first source of errors by writing your code in c++ against the sdk headers. Once you know how to use the interface translate it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working in C#? I have tried your code above, and the suggested 'Answer' code by @simon-mourier and continue to get the E_FAIL result. However, this method works correctly in C++. I have verified in C++ that the IID and CLSID values you have above are correct. I have also verified that passing the 'refPath' param of GetPath as a 'ref' causes memory corruption. I have also tried that method by using 'IntPtr' values for the first and second parameters with the same E_FAIL result.

Comment: @dahall yes, it is working for me, but I noticed that I'm using different type marshallings and not passing by-reference value. I edited the code above with these changes that are working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface definition is wrong because you did not defined methods in the same order as MSDN does (in fact, names are not important, what's important is the interface methods layout: matching binary signatures in the correct order). The order *must* be exactly what's defined in .h files available with the Windows SDK, not what MSDN displays - this is actually misleading :-).  In this case, the header file is     Shobjidl.h. This is how it's defined in C/C++:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("D11AD862-66DE-4DF4-BF6C-1F5621996AF1")
IOpenControlPanel : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Open( 
        /* [string][unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string LPCWSTR pszName,
        /* [string][unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string LPCWSTR pszPage,
        /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt IUnknown *punkSite) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPath( 
        /* [string][unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt_string LPCWSTR pszName,
        /* [size_is][string][out] */ __RPC__out_ecount_full_string(cchPath) LPWSTR pszPath,
        /* [in] */ UINT cchPath) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCurrentView( 
        /* [out] */ __RPC__out CPVIEW *pView) = 0;

};
```

There are multiple equivalent definition in .NET, C#, but here is one that should work:

```
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("D11AD862-66DE-4DF4-BF6C-1F5621996AF1")]
    public interface IOpenControlPanel
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Open([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string name,
                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string page,
                                                   IntPtr punkSite);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string name,
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder refPath,
                                                      int bufferSize);

        // if you remove PreserveSig, you can return the [out] param directly
        // note in this case, the function could throw instead of returning an error int like with PreserveSig
        ControlPanelView GetCurrentView();
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I only want to comment that the actual definition of **GetPath** will throw an exception of invalid access to memory read-write related to the marshallings, why rollback the fix I did?.

Comment: I suppose your first sentence has a typo. Did you want to say: "you did NOT define methods in the same order as MSDN does"?

Comment: This suggested interface definition works correctly for the Open and GetCurrentView methods, but still produces an E_FAIL result when calling the GetPath method.

Comment: @dahall - this is not a problem of the interface definition. Try with null or "Microsoft.DefaultPrograms" and you'll see it works.

Comment: After a frustrating few hours, I found the scenario that causes this to fail (and consequently to work). The C# project must be built with Platform Target set to "x64". If set to "Any CPU" or "x86", this interface definition will fail if you pass anything but `null` for the `name` parameter of `GetPath`.

Comment: It will also work if built with "Any CPU" and "Prefer 32-bit" unchecked.